# WAF is set to Alert, not block. We are seeing thousands of XSS and SQL Injection attacks. How can I tell if any were actually successful?

Tags: xss, sql-injection, waf

I'm pretty inexperienced with WAFs and the events/alerts it generates. I'm wondering how I can tell if any of those were successful?   For example, in the last 24 hours we saw over 50K alerts/events of 941330 (Core Rule Set).   I know there is a high propensity for False Positives with this event (and others), but before we start blocking, I want to understand better what is happening and what is successful.

Comment: Success is defined by your server. You need to look at your web server and database logs